Build input file cannot be found: Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
i just moved some files to group by creating a group in my xcode
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/apple/Desktop/Reptech iOS Apps July/Workout Plan Creator/Workout Plan Creator/Info.plist'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

a proper solution without fiddling Clean Up Build or "Hard Clean" or Renaming of Projects..
in Xcode 10+, and i think even earlier versions, goto..
Left Panel
select Workspace
then select .xcodeproj
the middle section should present project settings by now
in the middle section the right side shows your Project and its Targets, select the Target.
from the presented Tabs choose Build Settings
use the search field to find CLANG_USE_OPTIMIZATION_PROFILE, or type optim.. to filter all available options.
by now you should see the section for Apple Clang - Code Generation
in which you will find the build option CLANG_OPTIMIZATION_PROFILE_FILE.
That is the location of the profile that is missing. You could change that.
If you want to stop the use of profiling then just switch
Use Optimisation Profile aka CLANG_USE_OPTIMIZATION_PROFILE to NO

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
